# Deleting default constructor causes problems with default allocator in STL containers

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, stl, allocator

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class PasswordCategory
{
public:
    PasswordCategory(const std::string&);
    ~PasswordCategory();

    PasswordCategory() = delete;
    ...
}
```

This results in a compiler error related to allocators:

> error C2280: 'PasswordCategory::PasswordCategory(void)' : attempting
>   to reference a deleted function 
>  File: xmemory0:577

IDE is VS 2013 Community.

I am assuming that this occurs because somewhere else I am using vector of these categories.

```
std::vector<PasswordCategory> m_categories;
```

I only insert elements into it using emplace_back(string), however, it seems that the default allocator for PasswordCategory is trying to use the default constructor for PasswordCategory, but since that is deleted, it throws an error.

If I provide the default constructor, it all works fine, but I am wondering how I can mitigate this issue without a default constructor, if at all?

I thought of the following solutions:

1. Providing a custom allocator for my class that constructs my class. However, this doesn't solve the problem that I want my string argument to be non-optional.
2. Providing the default constructor that just calls my other constructor with some argument. This also doesn't solve the problem that this argument is non-optional and shouldn't really be defaulted.
3. Using a vector of references or pointers instead of a vector of values. This seems like the most rational solution, however it introduces the need to manage our memory manually, unless we use unique_ptr or something similiar.

I am wondering if I can somehow prohibit arg-less construction of my class, while still being able to use it in standard containers by value?

Any answers and insights are appreciated, thanks in advance.

P.S. This is for a small project of mine that I am doing in order to better understand C++, where I am trying to avoid most of the common pitfalls and make everything as reliable as possible, so that when I am going to work on a bigger project, it will be easier for me to avoid these common pitfalls. I tried formulating the question in different manners, but didn't find an answer for my question, so instead I'm asking my own one.

Comment: Could you show us exactly what you're doing with the vector to cause the error? It should work, if the implementation conforms to C++11/14, as long as you don't do anything that specifically needs a default constructor (e.g. call `resize` with a single argument). Defining an empty vector, and calling `emplace_back` with appropriate constructor argument(s), should be fine.

Comment: Ah, this is curious. After reading your comment I actually managed to find the culprit. I was initializing my vector with a 0 argument:
`PasswordManager::PasswordManager() : m_categories(0) {}`
After making it `m_categories()`, the code compiled.

I thought initializing a vector of size 0 would not cause the instantiation of the default allocator. In-fact, I thought it would be better, since it's more verbose, and clearly shows that the vector starts out as empty. Turns out I was wrong.

Comment: You were telling the vector to populate itself with N default constructed elements, which takes a code path that requires a default constructor for your type (even if the run-time value of N is 0). By default-constructing the vector you say you want it empty, which doesn't require any constructor for your type.

Comment: Indeed, that constructor contains code to default-initialise the elements - since that's what it's specified to do - so it's an error whether or not that code is actually executed.

Comment: N.B. you don't actually need to delete your default constructor, the existence of the `PasswordCategory(const std::string&)` constructor means there is no default constructor anyway.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I now see what was the problem here. Lesson learned - don't explicitly initialize a vector with 0 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` itself doesn't require `T` to be a `DefaultConstructible` type:

**Until C++ 11:**

> T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.

**Since C++ 11:**

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for details.

You may, however, perform operations on container, that involve creating implicit instances and that's why you get this error. If you can track them and eliminate them, everything should work fine, as default constructor will simply not be required if it is not used.

Considering your proposals:

**1.** Providing a custom allocator for my class that constructs my class.

This won't help - `std::allocator` is not responsible for default-contructing elements, because it simply does not define such functionality. See [std::allocator::construct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct).

**EDIT**
Little mistake here, I didn't noticed small change in C++ 11:

**Until C++ 11**

```
void construct( pointer p, const_reference val );
```

**Since C++ 11**

```
template< class U, class... Args >
void construct( U* p, Args&&... args );
```

**2.** Providing the default constructor that just calls my other constructor with some argument.

This also doesn't solve the problem that this argument is non-optional and shouldn't really be defaulted.
This is also not fully portable. Some compilers (like VC11) does not support delegating constructors.

**3.** Using a vector of references or pointers instead of a vector of values.

This seems like the most rational solution, however it introduces the need to manage our memory manually, unless we use unique_ptr or something similiar.
Not quite valid - you can't create container of references. The closest solution would be container, that holds [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s. Container of raw/smart pointer is also an option, but that's the point, where things are started to get messy.

Also, in your original code, there is no need to declare deleted default constructor - if you declare **any** constructor, it means that there is no default one (unless you define it) and compiler won't generate any.

Comment: In C++11 `std::allocator::construct(T*)` will be used for default-constructed elements

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, you're right, I forget about changes made in `std::allocator` with C++ 11. Answer updated, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In principle, you cannot: standard containers require contained objects to be default-constructible</strike>. (see comment from Mike Seymour).

In principle you should be able to, unless you use operations that require default construction internally.

That said, you can simply create an empty constructor (that defaults members to something sane/calls another constructor with some arguments). If you write client code correctly, you will not encounter your object, initialized with default values.

The operations that require default construction of objects are usually resize, and a few others that require creating internal objects (i.e. unless you want to reserve an element and use it without initializing it explicitly, you should not have a problem).

Comment: "standard containers require contained objects to be default-constructible" - no they don't, since C++11. Only a few specified operations need that.